# Python module threading as daemon with logging

Tags: python, multithreading, module, daemon

I am trying to create a module `init` and a module `mydaemon` in Python 2.7 under Debian 7.

The module `init` checks the requirements such as db connections etc. Then,  `mydaemon` runs in a thread and uses the database to do things and write a logfile.

The problem when setting up the thread daemon is that the logging and function call fails. 
But if the thread not daemon working fine...

Where am I wrong or what will be a better approach?

**init.py**

```
import mydaemon, threading

print 'start'
t = threading.Thread( target = mydaemon.start, args = () )
t.daemon = True # error here
t.start()
```

**mydaemon.py**

```
import logging

def start():
   work()
   return

def work():
   logging.basicConfig( filename = 'mylog.log', level = logging.DEBUG )
   logging.info('foo log')
   print 'foo console' 
   return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My collage found another method with external Daemon module (python-daemon)

http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html

In the tutorial have some error but read comments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Making it as a deamon means the background thread dies as soon as the main app closes. Your code 'works' as is, simply add a pause to init.py to model this behavior:

```
...
t.start()

import time
time.sleep(1)
```

This is discussed in more detail at http://pymotw.com/2/threading/#daemon-vs-non-daemon-threads.

The simply way to fix this is to join the thread.

```
import mydaemon, threading

print 'start'
t = threading.Thread( target = mydaemon.start, args = () )
t.daemon = True # error here
t.start()
t.join()
```

Comment: Hi, the logging still fail, but the file is created.

Comment: Ah, sorry tried this on a windows system not debian. The issue is because when it's made as a thread, the thread will die as soon as the main program dies. So it doesn't have enough time to write to the file before the main program exists. I will update my answer.

Comment: A concise and helpful starting point (in German) is https://www.thomaschristlieb.de/ein-python-script-mit-systemd-als-daemon-systemd-tut-garnicht-weh/ [Auto-Translatation](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thomaschristlieb.de%2Fein-python-script-mit-systemd-als-daemon-systemd-tut-garnicht-weh%2F)